# Two or more objects have the same target location '<location>'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, windows-installer, installation

I'm trying to Build a Deployment project wich has some dll dependencies, and I'm getting this error while building :

> Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\icon.ico')

I've tried to remove the file and do the same thing as this answer : [VS2010 (older) installer project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906051/vs2010-older-installer-project-two-or-more-objects-have-the-same-target-locat)

But I get always the same error.

I found also this : [Condition Property  from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhx4ah11%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

But I don't have any condition before adding the icon to the installation folder.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename one icon.ico file that is included in one of the projects.

Comment: You can either remove that file from one dependency in the setup project or move that file to another folder in the setup. Or copy icon.ico to another location and rename and add that as the reference for one of the projects.

Answer (score 2):

I still regularly get this error in VS2017 when no change has occurred that should be causing this exception.  Every time it happens I find that closing VS and then restarting it sorts it out.

Obviously this won't fix scenarios where there's a structural fault causing it, but it does seem that there are still many issues in the VS installers that can be solved by simply restarting VS - I think VS doesn't take kindly to the project configuration being changed sometimes (e.g. from Debug to Release).